# How to pass arguments from two different functions

Tags: c++

I've got a basic question:

There is a function that can take six arguments:

```
 void dataSlot(double val1, double val2, double val3, double val4, double val5, double val6);
```

How can I pass those arguments from two different functions, simultaneous?

```
void functionOne()
{

// val1, val2 and val3 from functionOne


}

void functionTwo()
{

// val4, val5 and val6 from functionTwo


}
```

Comment: Why did you make them as a void function?

Comment: What do you mean by "simultaneous"? Where are you calling `dataSlot()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the values each function produces and use them when you have all the values:

```
#include <array>

std::array<double, 3> functionOne()
{
    // ...
    return {val1, val2, val3};
}

std::array<double, 3> functionTwo()
{
    // ...
    return {val4, val5, val6};
}

void overallFunction()
{
    auto firstThree = functionOne();
    auto lastThree = functionTwo();
    dataSlot(firstThree[0], firstThree[1], firstThree[2], lastThree[0], lastThree[1], lastThree[2]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create variable in your file then set it from your first void;

```
double v1, v2, v3....;

void dataSlot(double val1, double val2, double val3....) {
    v1 = val1;
    v2 = val2;
    v3 = val3;
    ....
}
```

Then you can use v1 v2 and v3 everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

You can try add to youre fnc:void functionOne(double val1, double  val2, double val3) {do smthng}
void functionTwo(double val4, double  val5, double val6){do smthng}
and start it from void dataSlot(){functionOne (1,2,3);functionTwo(4,5,6) }